# Peta Poco and System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography

Tags: c#, petapoco

I get an error

```
"Object must implement IConvertible."
```

When I

```
Database db = new Database(this.ConnStr, this.Provider);
var x = db.Fetch<myObj>(sql);//returns the error
```

and myObj has a

```
System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography
```

property. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PetaPoco maintainer here. The error is because PetaPoco doesn't know about the type and defaults to trying `Convert.ChangeType(src, dstType, null);`, which is where I believe the error is originating from.

Please raise an issue [over at the repo](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco) if you'd like support this type built-in.

A quick fix would be for you to implement your own converter logic. An example of this can be found in the [SQLite integration test code](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/blob/master/PetaPoco.Tests.Integration/Databases/Sqlite/SqliteDBTestProvider.cs). If you don't want to use the ConventionMapper or you're using an older version of PetaPoco, you can always register a customer mapper for the specific type. See the [mapping docs](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Mapping-Pocos) for more information.

Comment: I didn't have the need to query the geography type in SqlServer so I converted it to nVarChar max. Converted within c# but it would be useful for Peta Poco to be able to do this. EF6 does but I don't like EF6. Thanks.

Comment: I love PetaPoco too. Make sure you check out the newer releases. I've added a few nice features and there's lots of bug fixes too ;)